# SQL-запрос: проблема с записью во вторую таблицу

Tags: sql

Помогите с sql-запросом, данные записываются только в первую таблицу, во вторую - не хотят.

```
$q = "UPDATE users SET email='$email',flname='$flname',fllogin='$fllogin',country_code='$country_code' where pk_user = '$userkey'";
"UPDATE comments SET email='$email' where id_commenter='$userkey'";
```

Comment: это вы с помощью php делаете? ($q)

Comment: sql........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$q = "UPDATE users SET email='$email',flname='$flname',fllogin='$fllogin',country_code='$country_code' where pk_user = '$userkey'" +
"UPDATE comments SET email='$email' where id_commenter='$userkey'";
```

или

```
$q1 = "UPDATE users SET email='$email',flname='$flname',fllogin='$fllogin',country_code='$country_code' where pk_user = '$userkey'";
$q2 = "UPDATE comments SET email='$email' where id_commenter='$userkey'";
```

не?

Comment: скорее за все долно было быть так:
`$q = "UPDATE users SET email='$email',flname='$flname',fllogin='$fllogin',country_code='$country_code' where pk_user = '$userkey'; UPDATE comments SET email='$email' where id_commenter='$userkey'";`